# Rotate object also around self center?

Tags: ios, math, cocos2d-iphone, linear-algebra

```
star.rotation += star.speed;
float angleRadian = star.rotation * PI_DIV_180;
star.position = ccp(windowSize.width/2 + (star.radius * sinf(angleRadian)), windowSize.height/2 + (star.radius * cosf(angleRadian)));
```

Above is rotating `star` sprite along window center point when calling for every frame. Anchor point is center of star. How can I make the star to rotate along self center as well?

Comment: self center, you mean rotate the star around its center? Isn't that what you're doing with star.rotation += star.speed?

Comment: yes I mean around its center. It's not what I'm doing now. I'm currently performing translation AND rotation in order to rotate star around windowSize center. Like Earth is rotating around sun and around its own axis is what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: If you translate the star to (x,y), does its *center* go to (x,y)?

Comment: @Beta the center relative to window goes to x,y. The center relative to star remains unchanged.

Comment: perhaps I'm misunderstanding you, but it seems like you are trying to use the star's rotation as a part of it's position, but you want to decouple the relationship between the rotation and position... so why don't you just create another variable that represents it's relativeAngle or similar, and use rotation as it is, which is the (local) rotational angle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want objects that orbit around each other, as well as spin/rotate on their own axis? Something like this?

RotationTest.h

```
@interface RotationTest : CCLayer
{
    CCSprite *star;
    CCSprite *planet;
    CCSprite *satellite;

    float dist_star_planet;
    float dist_planet_satellite;

    float relative_angle_star_planet;
    float relative_angle_planet_satellite;
}

@end
```

RotationTest.m

```
#import "RotationTest.h"

@implementation RotationTest

-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init]))
    {
        CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

        star = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Icon.png"];
        planet = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Icon.png"];
        satellite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Icon.png"];

        [self addChild: star];
        [self addChild:planet];
        [self addChild:satellite];

        star.position = ccp(s.width / 2.0f, s.height / 2.0f);
        planet.position = ccpAdd(star.position, ccp(100.0f, 0.0f));
        satellite.position = ccpAdd(planet.position, ccp(50.0f, 0.0f));

        star.scale = 0.5f;
        planet.scale = 0.35f;
        satellite.scale = 0.2f;

        dist_star_planet = ccpDistance(planet.position, star.position);
        dist_planet_satellite = ccpDistance(satellite.position, planet.position);

        relative_angle_star_planet = 0.0f;
        relative_angle_planet_satellite = 0.0f;

        [self scheduleUpdate];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) update:(ccTime) dt
{
    star.rotation += 1.0f; // degs
    planet.rotation -= 1.0f;
    satellite.rotation += 2.0f;

    relative_angle_star_planet += 0.01f; // rads
    relative_angle_planet_satellite -= 0.01f;

    planet.position = ccpAdd(star.position, ccp(dist_star_planet * sinf(relative_angle_star_planet), dist_star_planet * cosf(relative_angle_star_planet)));
    satellite.position = ccpAdd(planet.position, ccp(dist_planet_satellite * sinf(relative_angle_planet_satellite), dist_planet_satellite * cosf(relative_angle_planet_satellite)));
}

@end
```

Comment: Exactly. Let me figure out this and see if I can set position and rotation of each star to my Box2D body. I'm using `SetTransform(pos, angle)` there.

Answer (score 0):

A rotation will always rotate around `(0,0)` so you just have to translate the point `p` you want to be the center to `(0,0)` roate by your angle and then translate back!

Edit:

So if you want to have to rotation axis, the first being the center of your screen `p` and the second beeing the center of your star `q` with rotation angles `P` and `Q`.

```
Set Star to (0,0) rotate by Q
Translate Star by the distance you want around p
Rotate by P
Translate (0,0) to p
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand. Rotation will rotate around center of sprite as its anchor point is set to 0.5, 0.5 by default. If you could give me some example in code that would be more understandable.

Comment: yeah wait try to find sth1

Comment: @Pablo 

wait you basically want a star that's rotating around itself. And then beeing rotated around the center of the screen?

Comment: yes, that's what I want. Now it's rotating along center of the screen, always facing to the center. I want the star to rotate also around its axis.

Comment: Wait you're telling me that if the earth is the center of your screen. From earth the star is just seen from the same side? Like the Moon in real?

Comment: not the earth is the center of the screen, but the sun in this example. I can show visual example if needed.

Comment: Nono, I just took the earth, because you will always the the same side of the moon from earth!

Comment: So if that is your case then you have to change the rotation speed of your star! 
O

Comment: If I change rotation speed it will rotate faster or slower around center of screen. I want to have 2 speeds a) center of screen rotation speed b) self center rotation speed (and direction)